# Перенос текста в ie для flex-элементов не работает

Tags: css, internet-explorer, flexbox

Перелопатила всю выдачу поисковиков, пытаясь решить проблему. 
И ничего не получилось.

Конкретно в IE у меня работает уже практически всё, кроме этой гадости.
**wbr** не помогает, к сожалению. Подскажите, как решить проблему.
Хочется, чтобы и на IE все корректно отображалось. Раз уж я все остальное практически адаптировала.

Спасибо!

Вот скриншот (заголовки и описания соседних элементов накладываются друг на друга):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот html:

```css
.container {all: initial;
      text-align: center;}

.wrapper {
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-justify-content: center;
          justify-content: center;
 text-align: center;
  text-align:-webkit-center;
  -webkit-align-items: center;
          align-items: center;
  -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
          flex-wrap: wrap;
 -webkit-align-self: center;
         align-self: center;
}

.choice {
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-flex-direction: column;
          flex-direction: column;
  background-image: url(Plan.jpg);
  width: 200px;
  height: 250px;
  margin: 5px;
  border: 1px solid #D3D3D3;
  text-align: center;
  -webkit-align-items: center;
          align-items: center;
}

.justify-content-between { 
  -webkit-justify-content: center; 
          justify-content: center;
 } 

 .flex-wrap {
  -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
          flex-wrap: wrap;
 }


.container { width: 80%; margin: 0 auto; 
   inherit: none;} 

 .d-flex { display: -webkit-flex; display: flex; }
 
 
 break{
  -webkit-flex-basis: 100%;
          flex-basis: 100%;
  width: 0px; 
  height: 0px; 
  overflow: hidden;
}
 
  @media screen and (max-width: 1505) .line-break {  width: 100%;}
 
  @media screen and (
   max-width: 1488) {
    .line-break {
  width: 0%;}
  .container {inherit: none; 
   width: 40%;
   max-width: 1200 px;
   margin: 0 auto; } 
}
 
  @media screen and (max-width: 1100) {
  .container {inherit: none;
   width: 95%;}
   nav {-webkit-align-content:  center;align-content:  center;}
   .wrapper {
  -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
          flex-wrap: wrap;
-webkit-flex-direction:column;
        flex-direction:column;
  
 -webkit-align-self: center;
  
         align-self: center;
}
}
 @media screen and (max-width: 1487) {
  break {display: none;}
 }
 
  @media (max-width : 800px)
{ 
    .show-on-mobile { display: inline; }
    .hide-on-mobile { display: none; }
}
  @media (min-width: 801px)   
{   
    .show-on-mobile { display: none; }
    .hide-on-mobile { display: inline; }
}      
        
 
 @media screen and (min-width: 1488 and max-width: 2193) {
  section: nth-child(3n) 
   after;
 }

Вот html:
```

```html
<div class="container">
          <nav class="wrapper d-flex justify-content-between flex-wrap">
            <section class="choice" onclick="location.href='http://www.baseflat.ru/database.html';">
              <figure>
                <h3><a href="">Последнее обновление</a></h3>
                <br>
                <img src="Today-final.jpg" alt="Все квартиры за сегодня"> <figcaption>Адреса
                  и описания / Все варианты за сегодня</figcaption> </figure>
            </section>
            <section class="choice" onclick="location.href='http://www.baseflat.ru/area.html';">
              <figure>
                <h3 class="select"><a href="">По районам СПб</a></h3>
                <br>
                <img src="Metro-distr-final.jpg" alt="Квартиры по районам и метро">
                <figcaption>Длительная аренда по районам и метро</figcaption> </figure>
            </section>
            <section class="choice" onclick="location.href='http://www.baseflat.ru/sut.html';">
              <section class="line-break"></section>
              <figure>
                <h3><a href="">Посуточные квартиры</a></h3>
                <br>
                <img src="Sutochno-final.jpg" alt="Аренда на несколько дней"> <figcaption>
                  Квартиры в аренду на короткие сроки</figcaption> </figure>
            </section>
            <section class="choice" onclick="location.href='http://www.baseflat.ru/database.html';">
              <figure>
                <h3><a href="">Однокомнатные квартиры</a></h3>
                <br>
                <img src="1KKV-final.jpg" alt="Снять однокомнатную квартиру в СПб">
                <figcaption>Снять однокомнатную квартиру в СПб</figcaption> </figure>
            </section>
            <section class="choice" onclick="location.href='http://www.baseflat.ru/area.html';">
              <figure>
                <h3><a href="">Двухкомнатные квартиры</a></h3>
                <br>
                <img src="2KKV-final.jpg" alt="Снять двухкомнатную квартиру в СПб">
                <figcaption>Снять двухкомнатную квартиру в СПб </figcaption> </figure>
            </section>
            <section class="choice" onclick="location.href='http://www.baseflat.ru/sut.html';">
              <figure>
                <h3><a href="">Трехкомнатные квартиры и более</a></h3>
                <br>
                <img src="3KKV-final.jpg" alt="Снять трех-, четырехкомнатную квартиру в СПб">
                <figcaption> Снять трехкомнатную, четырехкомнатную ...</figcaption>
              </figure>
            </section>
          </nav>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуй у figure задать max-width: 100%

Comment: Спасибо! Теперь все отображается, как нужно!